# The orthocentre of a triangle is $(-3,5)$ and circumcentre is $(6,2)$ then find the centroid of the triangle.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

The orthocentre of a triangle is $(-3,5)$ and circumcentre is $(6,2)$ then find the centroid of the triangle.

My Attempt:

We know that the centroid is the point of intersection of the three medians of a triangle. It divides the median in the ratio of $2:1$.

Now, how do I proceed further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint Eulers line tells us that the centroid divides the line joining circumcenter and orthocenter in the ratio $2:1$ where $\frac {cg}{go}=\frac {2}{1} $

Comment: I couldn't understand. Please elaborate.

Comment: If circumcenter=c,g=centroid,o=orthocenter then distance between cg=2go can you  now find point using internal dvision formula. Hope you got it

Comment: Euler's line says that the centroid is 2/3rd along the line joining the circumcentre and orthocentre.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar, You mean
$$(x,y)=(\dfrac {m_1x_2+m_2x_1}{m_1+m_2} , \dfrac {m_1y_2+m_2y_1}{m_1+m_2})$$??????

Comment: Yes exactly. .....